# Proving that a Boolean algebra only has 2 elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, boolean-algebra

We define a Boolean algebra as a set $B$ of elements $a,b,\dots$ which satisfies the following axioms$^{[1]}$:

1. $B$ has two binary operators $\wedge$ or $\cdot$ (logical AND) and $\vee$ or $+$ (logical OR)
2. Idempotence

   - $a\wedge a = a \vee a = a$
3. Commutative law

   - $a \wedge b = b \wedge a$
   - $a \vee b = b \vee a$
4. Associative law

   - $a \wedge (b \wedge c) = (a \wedge b) \wedge c$
   - $a \vee (b \vee c) = (a \vee b) \vee c$
5. Absorption law

   - $a \wedge (a \vee b) = a \vee (a \wedge b) = a$
6. Mutual distributiveness

   - $a \wedge (b \vee c) = (a \wedge b) \vee (a \wedge c)$
   - $a \vee (b \wedge c) = (a \vee b) \wedge (a \vee c)$
7. $B$ contains universal bounds $\emptyset$ (empty set) and $I$

   - $\emptyset \wedge a = \emptyset$
   - $\emptyset \vee a = a$
   - $I \wedge a = a$
   - $I \vee a = I$
8. $B$ has a unary operator $a\rightarrow a'$ such that

   - $a \wedge a' = \emptyset$
   - $a \vee a' = I$

How can I prove that $B$ is composed of only 2 truth elements $x, y\in B$? I feel like it should come from Axioms 7 and 8, but I couldn't come up with a rigorous proof.

---

[1]http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BooleanAlgebra.html

Comment: Why do you think it only has two elements?

Answer (score 3):

A Boolean algebra need not have only two elements.  For instance, if $X$ is any set, then you could take $B$ to be the set of all subsets of $X$, with $\wedge$ being intersection, $\vee$ being union, $\emptyset$ being the empty set, $I$ being $X$, and $a'$ being $X\setminus a$.  All the axioms are then just familiar properties of basic set operations.

Comment: But will it always have $2^n$ elements? Why do we so commonly deal with  true/false;1/0 as being the only elements of $B$?

Comment: @BernardMeurer It is well known that the power set of a finite set has $2^{|X|}$ elements.

Comment: @0celo7 That makes no sense to me. Could you please explain?

Comment: @BernardMeurer For any set $X$, the power set $P(X)$ is a boolean algebra, with union for $\vee$ and intersection for $\wedge$.